# Screen keeps getting half bugged every time I boot up Lubuntu/16.04.3

Tags: screen

[screen half bugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuAIi.jpg)

My Screen gets half bugged every time I boot up lubuntu, but if I suspend my netbook, when I come back the screen gets normal during the rest of use.
It didn´t happened during the boot up after the install, only occurring after the 200mb update from the update manager, which makes me suspect the update was responsable for it.

Comment: Please edit your question  to include the contents of /var/log/apt/history.log for that specific update. Please also add the specific release/flavor of Ubuntu that you are running.

Comment: I've tried to reinstall lubuntu and not allow update during and after the install, but even without the update the ptoblem still persists; then made a md5sum test in the ISO I used, to check if it could be the cause, still no problem was found in the ISO.